# Problem with Oci8 and php7. 4 on command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, zend-framework3

I have some troubles with my php7.4 and Oci8.
I have configured it in my apache2 installation and it works for the web application.
But when I try to execute a php script in command line, I get the following error : Oci8 can not be loaded.
I do not know why it works with my application but not in command line.
Any help or advice?

Comment: You most likely need to add the Oracle Instant Client libraries to your OS search path, e.g. PATH on Windows, or LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, Allright I will try it and keep you posted if everything goes well.

Comment: Problem solved. It was due to insufficient rights for our user on the folder in /var/www